# How can I pay a credit card bill for a company that doesn't provide an automatic payment service?

Tags: credit-card, billing, automation

Credo Credit Cards do not offer an automatic payment feature is there a way I can automatically pay the monthly statement automatically?

I checked mint.com's billpay and they only list credo mobile.

Comment: I don't believe any of my CCs offer automatic payments as an option. They make more money if you don't pay in full or miss a payment. Set up a checking account that has a Bill-Pay feature like briantist suggests.

Comment: Since my question was in regards to paying off a credit card I was looking for solution to pay a bill that changes every month.  A standard bill pay system is thus not good enough (setting a monthly recurring amount).  Thus I'm going to try mint bill pay and others may work as well if Credo offer's an "ebill" for a billpay system to hook into to know the the current bill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://bills.mint.com ended up having credo in their system but you can't find it if you search from their top bar.

In their current design you need to click "money" in the top nav and then search in the box in the middle of the page.

Answer (score 2):

Most bank accounts offer automatic bill pay as well. They don't rely on support from the bill you're paying, I think they basically just mail a check with your account number on it

Comment: If you're trying to pay off the entire balance each month, then this method can't be fully automatic, since you need to input the correct amount on your bank's website.

Comment: @MikeHaskel no argument here, I don't use third party bill payment myself and this is one reason.

Comment: This is how I pay 80% of my bills. CCs, utilities, loans, etc. If I know that the payment never changes, my checking account bill-pay feature lets me schedule it however I like and leave it.